# Why this code showing invalid use of group function?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE VIEW SALESMAN_WITH_MAX_ORDER AS 
    (SELECT S.Salesman_id,
            S.Name,
            S.City,
            Commission 
    FROM SALESMAN S,
         CUSTOMER C 
    WHERE S.Salesman_id=C.Salesman_id 
      AND Customer_id IN (SELECT Customer_id
                          FROM ORDERS
                          GROUP BY Customer_id,
                                   Ord_Date
                           HAVING SUM(PURCHASE_AMT) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(PURCHASE_AMT)) 
                                                       FROM ORDERS
                                                       GROUP BY Customer_id,
                                                                Ord_Date)));
```

Comment: Is this about mysql or about sql-server ? Please only keep one of these tags, they are both different products

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please tag correctly.

Comment: Sorry, this is about mysql.

Comment: Also it's **2022**, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for *30 years*; why have you not adopted it yet? [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the innermost query. You cannot do a MAX with a SUM as argument.

This is how you would do it in T-SQL, sorry I have no mysql to test it on right now.

```
CREATE VIEW SALESMAN_WITH_MAX_ORDER AS 
(
    SELECT S.Salesman_id,
        S.Name,
        S.City,
        Commission 
    FROM SALESMAN S,
        CUSTOMER C 
    WHERE S.Salesman_id=C.Salesman_id 
    AND Customer_id IN
    (
        SELECT Customer_id 
        FROM ORDERS 
        GROUP BY Customer_id,Ord_Date 
        HAVING SUM(PURCHASE_AMT)=
        (
            SELECT MAX(SUM_AMT)
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT SUM(PURCHASE_AMT) AS SUM_AMT
                FROM ORDERS 
                GROUP BY Customer_id,Ord_Date
            ) innerTableName
        )
    )
);
```